# Reading from serial prints garbage

Tags: c++, serial-port

I'm trying to configure a serial communication between a dsp and my computer.

The dsp sends the value of a 16-bit counter which increments each time it is sent.
So it's just counting...

Here is what I get on my computer :

> 3335
>   3336
>   3337
>   3338
>   36388
>   46920
>   16372
>   46919
>   3339
>   3340
>   3341
>   3342
>   36388
>   46920
>   16372
>   46919
>   3343
>   3344
>   4621
>   3341
>   36388
>   46920
>   ...

So we can see the counter which is interrupted by those 4 values that comes out of nowhere...

My program is configured with

```
fd = open(device.c_str(), O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, FNDELAY);
termios options;
tcgetattr(fd, &options);
cfsetispeed(&options, B4800);
cfsetospeed(&options, B4800);
options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD | CS8);
options.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);
options.c_iflag |= (IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);
tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options);
```

The DSP sends 4800/8N1.

Any idea ?

Comment: Where are the values getting converted from 16 bit binary into ASCII strings?  Before or after they go through the serial port?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly suspect those are being sent by the DSP, the serial port drivers are pretty well debugged by now.

Other possibilities are that you're reading the serial port from multiple threads at once (maybe in the same process, maybe not).  Open the port exclusively to make sure that isn't your problem.

Or, you could be reading the expected values from the serial port, and adding garbage in some buffering/queuing inside your program.  Possibly you're getting partial reads (due to receive timeout).

**Remember that the return value of `read` is measured in *bytes*, not *16-bit values*.  If you were receiving 8 bytes and then printing 8 shorts, you would see this sort of behavior.**  (However, the problems with the last two values, 4621 3341, in the "sequence" can't be explained this way.) *Based on comments from the OP, this appears to be the exact cause of the problem*

In no case is this problem attributable to serial port configuration.

Comment: Oh you pointed out my problem already... The problem with 4621 3341 can be explained by the fact that the buffer isn't totally filled at each loop.

Answer (score 0):

Lol I'm so sorry, the cause of the problem was elsewhere, I was doing

```
unsigned short buffer[4];
n = read(..., buffer, ...); // n in bytes !
```

Then

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) 
    dump << buffer[i] << std::endl;  // index in 16-bits !
```

So I was always reading my buffer of 4 items + 4 values (from the stack I guess)...

Thanks for your answers though...

Comment: Should I do something to close the question ?

Comment: Since it looks like I guessed correctly, you can "accept" my answer by clicking the outline of the checkmark.  This lets future readers know that my answer was able to solve your problem.  You should probably also change the title of your question to make it more accurate, something about extra garbage bytes in data from serial port, etc.  I've updated my answer to highlight which guess was correct.